# Android Java Running List of Action In separate Thread similar to C# style

Tags: java, android, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm .NET Developer but i have to make some code for Android in Java. I need to run 4 calculation operation and i want to make it in separate threads. I can simply create 4 thread and just run it but when device will have less than 4 cores ( e.g 1) it will be same or even less effective like just run in one thread. In C# i can create list of Action and then just run it in Parrarel like this :

C# CODE :

```
var actions = new List<Action>
{
    () => { // some action1},
    () => { // some action2},
    () => { // some action3},
    () => { // some action4},
}
Parallel.ForEach(actions, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = GetCoreCount() }, x => x());
```

And this will run and this will guarantee that each Action will be process on separate core ( More-Less)

Can I do some thing like this in Java on Android ?

I have no idea how to start this.

Only one thing that come to my head is some like this but this is ugly and ineffective.

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
if(cores = 1)
{
    // Create 1 Thread with action1,action2,action3,action4
}
if(cores = 2)
{
    //  Create 1 Thread with action1,action2
    // And Create 2nd Thread with action3,action4
}
if(cores = 3)
{
            //  Create 1 Thread with action1,
    // And Create 2nd Thread with action2
     // And Create 3rd Thread with action3
     // Thread that first end his action will pick up Action4
}
if(cores >= 4)
{
                    //  Create 1 Thread with action1,
    // And Create 2nd Thread with action2
     // And Create 3nd Thread with action3
    // And Create 4th Thread with action4
}
```

See even not codded this look very unclear and dirty ( and what when i add 5th action ? or will have 8 action and 8 cores ? )

Can i do something similar to C# ? With List of Action and Parallel execution limited by numbers of core ?

Thanks for advises :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a threadPoolExecutor https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Java handles the efficiency issues your worried about, and fyi a computer with one core/cpu will have multiple threads running, there will only be one running at any given time. But any modern computer has a lot of threads running simultaneously, it doesn't depend on how many cores/cpus are present/available.

Comment: So if i understand correctly. Even when i create more threads than phone will able to handle it will not block and thanks to threadPoolExecutor  Android will be able to control execution of Action in most efficient way ? I have 4 action that for 100 % will block 100 % of each CPU even on PC

Comment: I dont think it'll let you block 100%, the system is always running. And threads get blocked all the time, thats how we are able to have so many being run by the same processor or set of processors, they just normally dont get blocked for long unless they are waiting or sleeping.